Publishing WFS using GeoServer
I’ve installed GeoServer, imported a shapefile into it and created a WFS from it. I got the URL of the WFS (“localhost:8080…”) and set it up in QGIS on the same PC as where GeoServer is installed. It works, but it seems that the WFS I created can only be accessed by that particular PC rather than be accessible across the web to other users.
How do I create a WFS in GeoServer that can work on GIS software on other computers elsewhere?

change the proxy URL to the qualified name of your machine

Thanks Ian, but I’m not sure that I follow as I’m new to this.
If the WFS URL I used from the machine that has Geoserver and QGIS installed is http://localhost:8080/geoserver/WS_Test/ows?version=1.0.0&typeName=WS_Test%3ATest&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=gml3
The device name of that machine is DESKTOP-9PKB1RL.
Are you saying that the device name should be part of the URL?
Thanks.

You need to describe your set up in more detail if you want help. From the looks of if you're just running Geoserver out of the box on your PC using jetty. But without knowing there are way too many possibilities to give advice. You have to describe if you are behind any firewalls, for instance if you are on a company network or just at home , if you are using any reverse proxies, what webserver are you using etc.

"localhost" is a special DNS name which is hard-coded (by default) on most PCs to represent the local host (the local PC).  So "localhost:8080" will only work for connecting to the Geoserver from the same local host on which the Geoserver is running.  To connect from other PCs, replace "localhost" in the url with the IP address (or fully-qualified hostname) of the Geoserver PC.  Eg "123.123.123.123:8080" or "my-pc.local:8080".  (If you want to connect from PCs on another network across the internet, then you also need to deal with firewalls, routers, NAT, etc.)
